# How to change the content_scripts in background file (Chrome Extensions)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can i change the CSS file declared in content_scripts (manifest.json)?
I need to change it from background.js (style.css to style2.css)
Is it possible to do that?
The manifest.json:

```js
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 /* ... */
 /* ... */

 "background": {
  "scripts": [
   "files/script/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
   "files/script/background.js"
  ]
 },

 "permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "background",
  "browsingData",
  "cookies",
  "webRequest",
  "management",
  "storage"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*"],
  "css": [
   "files/css/style.css"
  ]
 }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change declared CSS in the manifest file.

But in order to run custom CSS programmatically from background script, you can use [chrome.tabs.insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS).

```js
// use a file
chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "style2.css"});

// use a CSS string
chrome.tabs.insertCSS({code: "body { background: red }" });
```